# Java out of eclipse build issue - Import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, build, compilation, scons

I have a problem building a java project. 
First, I must explain that we are performing the build outside of Eclipse, using a scons script to generate a final windows executable.

I know absolutly NOTHING at scons, and I am not capable at the moment to explain how the build is performed.

So, when the project has never been built, and when I try from the script, here is the first error that I get:

```
>[java] [javac] 1. ERROR in C:\1-Projets\Code\eclipse\plugins\com.xxx.yyy.ui\src\com\xxx\yyy\ui\Commands.java (at line 10)
>[java] [javac] import com.xxx.ggg.reflect.dyn.DynamicObjectTreeItem;
>[java] [javac] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>[java] [javac] The import com.xxx.ggg.reflect cannot be resolved
```

however, if I open Eclipse and that i perform a "build all", then there's absolutely no issue.

So currently, our only solution is to open Eclipse, wait for an automatic build to complete, close eclipse, and then we can build with no trouble using the script.

After this first build is done, there's absolutely no issue in building, ever. Until we delete and regenerate our build environment from scratch (which happens during the normal continuous integration process).

Also, I must say that I cleaned the project of 80 warnings (but the issue was there BEFORE), but I left untouched the build related warnings because I do not know which JRE is installed on the CI machine. SO I am putting a screen shot of these, just in case it could help.

[image: Build warnings]
Thanks very much.

Comment: Instead of opening Eclipse for the initial build, does it work when you call SCons a second time, so "scons; scons"?

Comment: Nope it does not, you really have to perform a build from eclipse. It generates some files and I guess those files are necessary for compilation

Those files looks like:
.../Commands$1$1.class
.../Commands$1$2.class
.../Commands$1.class

I guess that it's because of them that the lib import is no longer necessary (that's a equivalent of obj files in C++ ?). But if the command.java class is changed, and the project is not built, then it would mean that the scons build project would not take the changes into account.

Comment: This may be true, but it's impossible to tell without you providing more info about your project setup. Please try to compile a MWE, such that interested users can reproduce the issue on their sides.

Comment: What is a MWE ?
I have very little experience with java projects.

Thanks.

Comment: As always, Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Well, unfortunately, i won't be able to give any code since it is a protected & confidential source code. And i doubt I can reproduce an example by myself :(